# jQuery plugin throws 'not a function'

Tags: jquery

I have an auto-logout.js file which I include on some pages using:

```
<script src="/js/auto-logout.js"></script>
```

In the console it throws following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).idleTimeout is not a function

I don't understand why this is not working. Currently running jQuery 2.2.4.

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.idleTimeout = function(userRuntimeConfig) {
      // ...
    });
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).idleTimeout({
    idleTimeLimit: 1200,
    customCallback: function() {
      axios.get('/auth/signout').then(function() {
        document.location.reload();
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error)
      });
    },
    dialogDisplayLimit: 30,
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: idleTimeout is a jQuery plugin, did you include it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Use your browser to inspect your site's elements. Check if the script is loading.

Comment: Of course the script is loading, otherwise it wouldn't throw the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the package "materialize-css" broke my other scripts.
I updated 'materialize-css' to the latest 1.0.0 (from 0.98) and the issue was resolved.

Still don't know what caused the initial problem as this/these script(s) has/have been working just fine for years. Probably an issue because of an updated npm package somewhere.